# Что выбрать для большой матрицы - map area или div+css?

Tags: javascript, mysql

Задумал соединить в сеть несколько кофеен, столовых и т.д., для упрощения поиска все объединил в один массив посадочных мест.
Вывожу картинкой + map area (координаты беру из базы данных).
Cейчас готовый массив состоит из 200х200 мест (40000), каждое место в базе MySql - это 6 полей `int11` плюс 2 поля `varchar255`.
Подсвечиваю скриптом `maphilight`, а если использовать `div`,то подсветку занятых мест можно было бы реализовать через банальные классы и css!
Сейчас вроде бы выводит нормально, по сути там не все 40000 мест выводит, а пока что 1000 от силы, вот думаю, что сделать для оптимизаций вывода на страничке - оставить area+maphilight или все-таки div? Если все-таки придется выводить 40000 зон?

Comment: для 40к зон `DOM` будет лагать. может как вариант на `canvas` сделать?

Comment: Все 40к мест, думаю выводить все равно не будете, так-как, - это все же проще разбивать по страничкам. Ну, а на счет подсветки, лучше использовать клиент часть, нежели через сервер.

Comment: в том и фишка чтобы именно на одной страничке все сделать, пусть все зоны мелкими будут, главное визуальный охват. так все-таки area или div? а canvas чем лучше??? с базы данных приходит массив с числами, так что поправить не особо сложно, а вот сам вывод в браузере волнует...

Comment: почитал про canvas - вроде как малая совместимость с браузерами, только современные поддерживаются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Путем экспериментов на разных хостингах и на разных браузерах выяснил, что быстрее map плюс area!
Вывод **5000** элементов div прошел удачно в половине случаев, на мобильных гаджетах неудача в 90%. Более 5000 элементов почти везде полный провал.
Вывод одного map и внутри **50000** тегов area прошло безукоризненно на все подопытных ресурсах!!
Во всех вариантах нагрузка на БД минимальнейшая, т.е. сугубо браузерная война....
Юзаем map!