# Чем заменить теги area (map html), если их более 50000?

Tags: html

Нужно вывести на одну страницу довольно большой массив текстовых блоков, около 50000!! Нюанс в том, что текст надо показывать по наведению мышкой, то есть, возможно сам текст и не надо грузить изначально, а заранее нужно выгрузить и показать на странице только лишь сами блоки, их расположение.

Координаты хранятся в MySql.
Сначала игрался с `div` + `position:absolute`, но браузер банально вылетает в космос. Теперь тренируюсь на `map` + `area`.

Подскажите что еще можно применить в данном печальном случае?

Comment: Что подразумевается под блоками?

Comment: чем этот вопрос отличается от [этого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560446/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-map-area-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-divcss)?

Comment: Попробуйте разбить 50000 записей, к примеру, на 100 и, таким образом, сделайте так, что у вас будет 50000/100=500 индексов страницы и выводите по 500. А пользователи будут заходить на страницы через форму GET: первая страница = 1-500 записи, вторая страница = 501-1000 записи.. и так далее.

Comment: "чем этот вопрос отличается от этого?" там занятые незанятые места, тут текстовая информация, разные проекты абсолютно. ну и еще похожи автором))) может и похожи если изнутри смотреть. вроде бы два вопроса в одной топике нельзя?

Comment: один блок - один div